# asp.net Web API 2 AJAX fail

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

My test using Web API 2 is returning status 200 from AJAX fail method.

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] myData m)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("TEST")
        };
    }
```

myData class:

```
public class myData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Calling the POST from HTML:

```
    <html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var model = {
            Name: "Shyju",
            Id: 123
        };

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        url: "http://localhost:52884/api/contact",
        contentType: "application/json",
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function (response) {
            console.log("e : " + response)
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know why it isn't returning the message "TEST"?

Thanks

Comment: It is.  Use `res.data`  Also, use `then` instead of `done`.  `done` accepts two parameters, a resolve function and a reject function.  You're trying to treat the resolve function as data.  Refer to the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Do you mean res.data inside my console.debug? But it doesn't go to the done function

Comment: Where are you setting the status code to not be 200?

Comment: I'm not setting it. Should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Great way to throw an http exception in web api 2:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
                    new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                        ReasonPhrase = "Internal Server Error",
                        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myobject))
                    });
```

However, it is worth noting a simple throw exception statement causes a 500, which would do it too.  In my example, it's bypassing both error filtering & my global exception handler to just return an error status code and some error text to the UI.

Comment: Still returning the same problem. How can I debug a web api?